# How to combine data.frame object in multiple list efficiently without duplication?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have data.frame objects in multiple lists where some duplication exists. However, I intend to combine these data.frame object without duplication into one single list. I tried several ways to get expected output, but can't figure out how to combine data.frame object in multiple lists. Becuase in each list, the order of data.frame objects are very different. Does anyone know any trick of doing this manipulation easily? How can make this happen? any idea ? Thanks in advance.

This is quick reproducible example to run:

mini example:

```
myList_1 <- list(
  foo = data.frame(from=c(2,7,11,19), to=c(5,10,14,24), label=c("a1","a3","a5","a8"), score=c(2,5,8,12)),
  bar = data.frame(fom=c(12,17,21), to=c(15,19,25),label=c("b2","b3","b5"), score=c(7,3,6)),
  cat = data.frame(from=c(3,9,17,27), to=c(5,13,21,42),lable=c("c1","c3","c6", "c11"), score=c(5,2,4,9))
)

myList_2 <- list(
  bar = data.frame(from=c(7,12,27), to=c(10,15,36),label=c("b1","b2","b7"), score=c(4,7,11)),
  foo = data.frame(from=c(19,31,48), to=c(24,37,59),label=c("a8","a10","a15"), score=c(12,3,7)),
  cat = data.frame(from=c(6,17,22,27), to=c(12,21,25,42),label=c("c2","c6","c7","c11"), score=c(3,6,1,9))
)

myList_3 <- list(
  cat = data.frame(from=c(17,22, 45), to=c(21,25,58),label=c("c6","c7","c17"), score=c(4,1,5)),
  foo = data.frame(from=c(11,19,31,63), to=c(14, 24,37,71),label=c("a5","a8","a10","a19"), score=c(8,12,3,5)),
  bar = data.frame(from=c(27,57,72), to=c(36,66,83),label=c("b7","b14","b22"), score=c(11,2,8))
)
```

my desired output :

```
myList <- list(
  foo = data.frame(from=c(2,7,11,19,31,48,63),to=c(5,10,14,24,37,59,71),
                   label=c("a1","a3","a5","a8","a10","a15","a19"), score=c(2,5,8,12,3,7,5)),
  bar = data.frame(from=c(7,12,17,21,27,57,72),to=c(10,15,19,25,36,66,83),
                   label=c("b1","b2","b3","b5","b7","b14","b22"), score=c(4,7,3,6,11,2,8)),
  cat = data.frame(from=c(3,6,9,17,22,27,45),to=c(5,12,13,21,25,42,58),
                   label=c("c1","c2","c3","c6","c7","c11","c17"), score=c(5,3,2,4,1,9,5))
)
```

How can I get my output more easily/ efficiently ? How can I achieve my desired output ? Thanks a lot

Comment: I think there is a typo? in your input dataset with `lable` instead of `label`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `Map`.  Get the `names` of the first list ('myList_1') and use that to subset the other list elements so that it will be in the same order.  Then we `rbind` the corresponding data.frames of each `list` elements with `Map`.

```
nm1 <- names(myList_1)
Map(rbind, myList_1, myList_2[nm1], myList_3[nm1])
```

Comment: @Andy.Jian  It is from `base R`.  I find some typos in column names in your input dataset.  Is it intentional or accidental

Comment: @Andy.Jian The names are in different order and it is corrected by subsetting. using `myList_2[nm1]`, but the one I am talking about is `fom` instead of `from` , `lable` instead of `label`

Comment: @Andy.Jian You can use `map` instead of `Map` with `purrr`, but I don't find much advantage

Comment: @Andy.Jian  You can do this by `nm1 <- sort(names(myList_1))`

Comment: @Andy.Jian  I had problems in your dataset, perhaps try `Map(function(x,y,z) unique(rbind(x,y,z)), myList_1, my_List_2[nm1], myList_3[nm1])`